# Write CSV in Python 3.x without quotes for first line

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to find a way to write CSV file from other file.
The first line is the header and it must be written without quotes.
All other lines must be with quotes.

I tried to work with DictWriter to get the header and write all the rows but still all rows (with the header) are quoted.

Here's an example of what I wrote:

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(csvOutputFile, fieldnames=FileHeader.getFields(self), delimiter=',', quotechar='\"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
writer.writeheader()
```

The output file should look like that:

```
column1,column2,column3
"1111","2222","3333"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way would be to use 2 different csv writers on the same file object:

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(csvOutputFile, fieldnames=FileHeader.getFields(self),
    delimiter=',', quotechar='\"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
writer.writeheader()
writer = csv.DictWriter(csvOutputFile, fieldnames=FileHeader.getFields(self),
    delimiter=',', quotechar='\"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
# actually write the data to writer
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you could change the definition of `writer` from `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` to `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` after writing the header.

```
import csv

with open('eggs2.csv','w') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    spamwriter.writerow(['column1','column2','column3','column...'])
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
    spamwriter.writerow([1111, 2222, 33333])
```

Result:

```
column1,column2,column3,column...
"Spam","Spam","Spam","Spam","Spam","Baked Beans"
"Spam","Lovely Spam","Wonderful Spam"
"1111","2222","33333"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: @RolfofSaxony: I'm really sorry, I should have read your answer with more attention and only comment here instead of writing another answer. I only read the beginning of the code.